# returning one row, with the max date from two different columns from two different tables

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

Using report builder 3.0 for sql server 08 R2. Trying to get the most recent dates from 2 different columns in 2 different tables but I'm getting 4 rows instead of 1. In the picture below, there should be one row per patient.

Script I'm using is this:

```
SELECT "Patient"."PatientID", "PatientLastName", "PatientFirstName", "DischargeDate", "PatVisitPayable"."ContactDate"
FROM "BTI"."Patient" 
JOIN "BTI"."PatAdmissions" ON "Patient"."PatientID" = "PatAdmissions"."PatientID" 
JOIN "BTI"."PatVisitPayable" ON "PatAdmissions"."PatientID" = "PatVisitPayable"."PatientID" 
JOIN "BTI"."PatAdmissionDivision" ON "PatAdmissions"."AdmissionID" = "PatAdmissionDivision"."AdmissionID"
GROUP BY "Patient"."PatientID", "PatientLastName", "PatientFirstName", "DischargeDate", "ContactDate"
```

I've tried putting max(contactdate) and max(dischargedate) in the select statement but still get 4 rows. Wasn't sure if this is something I should include in the initial query or something I can add to the report afterwards.

[4 rows for one patient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0ZGT.png)

Comment: Do you really want the separate contact and discharge dates?  Wouldn't they normally correlate with each other for a single patient?

Comment: The dates are in regards to 2 different events. They're related to the same episode for a patient, but unfortunately our process and the program we use for our electronic medical record does not tie the contact to an episode/admission because it's done after the patient is discharged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `ContactDate` from `GROUP BY` clause and use `max()` function in `SELECT` :

```
SELECT pt.PatientID, 
       pt.PatientLastName, pt.PatientFirstName, pt.DischargeDate,                          
       MAX(ContactDate) as ContactDate
FROM BTI.Patient pt
JOIN BTI.PatAdmissions pa ON pt.PatientID = pa.PatientID
JOIN BTI.PatVisitPayable py ON pa.PatientID = py.PatientID 
JOIN BTI.PatAdmissionDivision pd ON pa.AdmissionID = pd.AdmissionID
GROUP BY pt.PatientID, pt.PatientLastName, 
         pt.PatientFirstName, pt.DischargeDate;
```

Always define table *alise* that could be easy to follow/read and write.
This assumes `ContactDate` in  resonbale format.

Comment: That did it! Thank you.